# Math: overwrite \int command

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath, math-operators, integral

I wish I could override the \ int command, so that each integral is rendered this way.

[image]

Yes, I know the command to display it this way is `\int\displaylimits_a^b`, but I would like to overwrite the original command.
Some idea?

Comment: `\let\oldint\int` and `\def\int{\oldint\displaylimits_a^b}`

Comment: Are you actually trying to fix the limits to be “a” and “b”? Or are you trying to change the integral to always have `\displaylimits`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\int` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\int{\intop\nolimits}
```

so you could simply use `\intop`  otherwise `\let\int\intop` if you want to use `\int`

Answer (score 23):

Use the relevant option in `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]